# App Crash when stop recording second time

Tags: android

working in recording when i am record first time this working fine but second time is starting recording and when stop then recording then it crash nad give **java.lang.IllegalStateException**

i dont underswtand why

**my code is**

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    session.checkLogin();
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    String name = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME);
    String email = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);
   //  outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";
    _Start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    _Stop =(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    _Send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendbtn);
    _Play =(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
    _CountTimer =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer_view);
    _ImgView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    if(!exists) {
        new File(path).mkdirs();
    }
    else {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(path + audioname);

    }
    _CountTimer.setText("00:30");
    final GumzoCounterClass timer = new GumzoCounterClass(30000, 1000);
    _Start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                try {
                    mRecorder.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mRecorder.start();
                timer.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            _ImgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            _Start.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            _Play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            _Stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start Recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    _Stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            _ImgView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            _Start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            _Stop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            _Play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mRecorder.stop();
            timer.cancel();
            _CountTimer.setText("Stoped Recording");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop Recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    _Play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();
             // _Start.setEnabled(false);
            try {
                m.setDataSource(outputFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                m.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            m.start();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
}

public class GumzoCounterClass extends CountDownTimer {
    public GumzoCounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }
    @Override

    public void onFinish() {
        _CountTimer.setText("Completed");
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        _CountTimer.setText((millisUntilFinished / 1000) + "");
    }
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.logout:
            AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
            if(accessToken != null){
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login_Activity.class));
                finish();
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Logout User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**My Logcate**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
at user.example.com.myApp.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:95)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

help me please

Comment: can we have logcat ?!

Comment: @NiravRanpara now i am updating logcate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are calling stop on a `null` object. You should check the `state` of your `MediaRecorder` before stopping

Comment: tahnks  but first time it's working properly how. i don't understand

Comment: try initializing mRecorder = new MediaRecorder(); inside onclick of  _Start

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official example from google](http://developer.android.com/samples/MediaRecorder/src/com.example.android.mediarecorder/MainActivity.html) you need to do the following when stop recording.

```
// stop recording and release camera
            mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
            releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
```

And `releaseMediaRecorder()` is look like,

```
private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
    if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
        // clear recorder configuration
        mMediaRecorder.reset();
        // release the recorder object
        mMediaRecorder.release();
        mMediaRecorder = null;
    }
}
```